# Rust macro_rules: nested repetition zips instead of producting

Tags: rust, macros

I'm currenly working on a macro that essentially transforms this:

```rust
// MyTrait is an existing trait
// Here I list default implementations of MyTrait's methods
trait MyTrait {
    fn f(&self, arg: i32) {
        println!("f default implementation: {}", arg);
    }

    fn g(&self) {
        println!("g default implementation");
    }
}

// No custom implementations, both f and g are default
struct A {}

// Custom implementation of g
struct B {
    fn g(..) {
        println!("g custom implementation");
    }
}
```

into this:

```rust
struct A {}

impl MyTrait for A {
    fn f(&self, arg: i32) {
        println!("f default implementation: {}", arg);
    }

    fn g(&self) {
        println!("g default implementation");
    }
}

struct B {}

impl MyTrait for B {
    fn f(&self, arg: i32) {
        println!("f default implementation: {}", arg);
    }

    // These two overloads will be later combined using proc_macro (or do you know a way to do it with macro_rules?)
    fn g(&self) {
        println!("g default implementation");
    }

    fn g(..) {
        println!("g custom implementation");
    }
}
```

Here is really simplified version of my code, minimal required to reproduce the macro issue:

```rust
macro_rules! impled_structs {
    (
        $($Struct:ident),*
        ;
        $($Method:ident),*
    ) => {
        $(
            struct $Struct {}

            impl $Struct {
                $(
                    fn $Method(&self) {}
                )*
            }
        )*
    };
}

impled_structs!(A, B; f, g, h);
```

The issue is that Rust just ignores `$()*` of `$(...$Method...)*` and treats the nested repetitions as a single `$(...$Struct...$Method...)` (i.e. zips them instead of cartesian producting) and throws the `` meta-variable `Struct` repeats 2 times, but `Method` repeats 3 times `` error. What can I do to make it generate its own `$(...$Method...)*` for every iteration of `$(...$Struct...)*`, i.e. product them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a nested `macro_rules!` macro to handle the sub-repetition.

```rust
macro_rules! impled_structs {
    (
        $($Struct:ident),*
        ;
        $($Method:ident),*
    ) => {

        // Create sub-macro to handle method generation
        macro_rules! methods {
            () => {
                $(fn $Method(&self) {})*
            };
        }

        // Invoke the sub-macro once for each repetition of $Struct.
        $(
            struct $Struct {}

            impl $Struct {
                methods!();
            }
        )*

    };
}

impled_structs!(A, B; f, g, h);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).