Is it possible to create match arms for every list item given as argument to a Rust macro?
I want to create a match by using a macro. I don't know how to do this, as I seem to miss how macros handle lists of elements (or maybe I am doing something else wrong).
My usecase: I have N generic types e.g. MyStructA<X: MyTraitTwo>, MyStructB<X: MyTraitTwo>, MyStructC<X: MyTraitTwo> (which implement trait TraitOne) where I use generic types as arguments X. I want to have N match-arms (for every struct MyStruct?). My actual use case has nested matches where I have e.g. M different types for X. So by hand I would have to write N * M match arms. But first the un-nested case:
fn create_type(arg: &str) -> impl MyTrait {
    make_match_arms![("a", MyStructA),("b", MyStructB), ("c", MyStructC)];
}

// would expand to:
fn create_type(arg: &str) -> impl MyTraitOne {
    match => arg {
        "a" => MyStructA<X>::new(),
        "b" => MyStructB<X>::new(),
        "c" => MyStructC<X>::new(),
    }
}

Ideally I could even simplify this to two lists of types that I give to a macro which would create match arms for every combination of these two elements. Like this (I omitted the generics, because I'm not sure if they can be used).
match (first_type_str, second_type_str) => {
every_combination![(MyStructA, MyStructB, MyStructC), (X1, X2, X3, X4, X5)]
};

It would look something like this:
fn return_combined_type(first: &str, second: &str) -> impl TraitOne<TraitTwo> {
    match first => {
        "a" => { 
                   match second => {
                       "1" => {MyStructA::<X1>::new(),
                       "2" => {MyStructA::<X2>::new(),
                       ...
                   },
        "b" => {
                   match second => {
                       "1" => { MyStructB::<X1>::new(),
                       ...
        ...

This would create 15 match arms - nested in 2 matches. Of course I would have to provide an argument that the arms match to (first, second) also to the macro, but I am not sure about how to do this right now.
I am not sure if I can properly explain this. Maybe someone is capable of reading between the lines and understands my problem.

This is impossible. It's not a question of macros, such a match is also impossible to write by hand because all match arms must return the same type, so there is no way to have an arm return MyStructA while another returns MyStructB

@Jmb is technically correct but, as in my answer, it's possible to translate impl MyTrait to Box<dyn MyTrait> to preserve OP's intentions (at least in the first part).

For the first part, we can use repetition:
#[allow(unused)]

fn main() {
    macro_rules! make_match_arms {
        ($arg:expr, $(($s:literal, $id:ident)),*) => {
            {match $arg {
                $(
                    $s => Box::new($id::<X>::new()),
                )*
                _ => panic!()
            }}
        }
    }
    
    struct MyStructA<T>(T);
    struct MyStructB<T>(T);
    struct MyStructC<T>(T);
    impl<T: Default> MyStructA<T> { fn new() -> Self { Self(Default::default()) } }
    impl<T: Default> MyStructB<T> { fn new() -> Self { Self(Default::default()) } }
    impl<T: Default> MyStructC<T> { fn new() -> Self { Self(Default::default()) } }
    trait MyTrait {}
    impl<T> MyTrait for MyStructA<T> {}
    impl<T> MyTrait for MyStructB<T> {}
    impl<T> MyTrait for MyStructC<T> {}

    fn create_type<X: Default + 'static>(arg: &str) -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
        make_match_arms![arg, ("a", MyStructA),("b", MyStructB), ("c", MyStructC)]
    }
}

Note: In order to make the program type-check, I wrapped each result in a Box such that each match arm produces a Box<dyn MyTrait>.
For the second part, we can use a nested macro for combinatorial repetition:
#[allow(unused)]

fn main() {
    macro_rules! every_combination {
        ($arg1:expr, $arg2:expr, ($(($s1:literal, $id1:ident)),*), ($(($s2:literal, $id2:ident)),*)) => {{
            macro_rules! inner {
                ($specificid1:ident) => {
                    {match $arg2 {
                        $(
                            $s2 => Box::new($specificid1::<$id2>::new()),
                        )*
                        _ => panic!()
                    }}
                }
            }
        
            match $arg1 {
                $(
                    $s1 => inner!($id1),
                )*
                _ => panic!()
            }
        }}
    }
    
    struct MyStructA<T>(T);
    struct MyStructB<T>(T);
    struct MyStructC<T>(T);
    impl<T: Default> MyStructA<T> { fn new() -> Self { Self(Default::default()) } }
    impl<T: Default> MyStructB<T> { fn new() -> Self { Self(Default::default()) } }
    impl<T: Default> MyStructC<T> { fn new() -> Self { Self(Default::default()) } }
    trait MyTrait {}
    impl<T> MyTrait for MyStructA<T> {}
    impl<T> MyTrait for MyStructB<T> {}
    impl<T> MyTrait for MyStructC<T> {}
    #[derive(Default)]
    struct X1;
    #[derive(Default)]
    struct X2;
    #[derive(Default)]
    struct X3;
    #[derive(Default)]
    struct X4;
    #[derive(Default)]
    struct X5;

    fn create_type(arg1: &str, arg2: &str) -> Box<dyn MyTrait> {
        every_combination![arg1, arg2, (("a", MyStructA), ("b", MyStructB), ("c", MyStructC)), (("1", X1), ("2", X2), ("3", X3), ("4", X4), ("5", X5))]
    }
}

Note: It was unclear what the intentions behind impl TraitOne<TraitTwo> are. I kept using a single trait, MyTrait.

There is a solution for combinatorial repetitions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73542258/rust-macro-rules-nested-repetition-zips-instead-of-producting (I feel like I remember there was another way to do it, but I can't find it now)

@kmdreko good to know; answer updated!
